# What does mean the @ (at) on unix access right?

Tags: php, unix, web, ls, access-rights

I have looked but it seems I did not found any question like mine.
I would like to know what does mean the `@` (*at sign*) on UNIX repository like as follow:

```
MacBook-de-Blouz:twentyfifteen ratinahirana$ ll
total 1136
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 ratinahirana  staff  376628 28 oct  2014 screenshot.png
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 ratinahirana  staff    1313 19 nov  2014 sidebar.php
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 ratinahirana  staff     902 19 nov  2014 page.php
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 ratinahirana  staff    1765 11 déc 09:24 index.php
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 ratinahirana  staff    1914 11 déc 09:24 archive.php
```

**NOTE:** I know the 777 is dirty ^^

Comment: See the documentation for the ls command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` symbol which you get from `ll` command (*alias of `ls -l`*) indicates which the file has **`extended attributes`**.

> **Wikipedia:**
>
> *Extended file attributes are file system features that enables users to associate computer files with metadata not interpreted by the filesystem, whereas regular attributes have a purpose strictly defined by the filesystem (such as permissions or records of creation and modification times) [...]*

You can use the command: `xattr -l <filename>` to show these attributes.

---

#### Related links:

- In the following link, **read** "*Symbolic notation*" inside "*Notation of traditional Unix permissions*".
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions
- More about `extended attributes` here: 
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes

Comment: Hi tomloprod, Thanks for your answer. It is interesting ^^

Comment: It is done. Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow :) I have checked out more information about the Extended Attributes.